# Limiting text display upto certain character Angular 4

Tags: javascript, html, string

I have raw html

```
`<p>High performing B School students often get courted by the top jobs in the market and often several people having to choose between Banking and Consulting. Avnish talks about how he made the decision to join Goldman Sachs after interning at McKinsey.&nbsp;</p>\r\n\r\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\r\n\r\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\r\n\r\n<p>&nbsp;</p>`
```

and I want to display the rendered text upto certain character.

I have used **slice** but it is also counting the html tag. 
I want to slice only the rendered text. Please suggest me a fix for this

Answer (score 0):

Using raw HTML in Angular isn't a good idea.

Also, since the question isn't about Angular but about JS, I have removed the tags you're using and used fitting ones.

Finally, know that by removing the HTML from your string, you won't be able to get it back (with this solution at least). I suggest you look at how Angular works, and how you should display the data
*(hint : `<p>{{ mySentence }}</p>`)*

Here is a quick way to get only the text of your raw HTML string :

```js
const raw = `<p>High performing B School students often get courted by the top jobs in the market and often several people having to choose between Banking and Consulting. Avnish talks about how he made the decision to join Goldman Sachs after interning at McKinsey.&nbsp;</p>\r\n\r\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\r\n\r\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\r\n\r\n<p>&nbsp;</p>`;

const div = document.createElement('div');

div.innerHTML = raw;

console.log(div.innerText);
```

Comment: It's not only <p> tag. It can be anything <div> or <div> within <div>

Comment: Inner text should return it anyways.